# Can I get the same solid compressed result from my meat press using cooked meats?

Tags: substitutions, meat, turkey

I'd like to turn the small pieces of leftover cooked turkey in to sliced deli meat using my meat press. However all the recipes I've found involve raw meats. Without the cooking step using a meat press, will my mixture hold itself together after pressing? Or will it be a loose spreadable 'potted meat'? Also, I'm afraid cooking my cooked leftovers will make it overcooked and undesirable...

Answer (score 2):

The chemical processes which bind chopped/minced raw meat during cooking do not happen when already-cooked meat is pressed, even if it is then reheated. If you add some concentrated aspic to the hot mixture, that may suffice to bind the pieces together once cooled, but it will not have the same consistency as meat that was raw when pressed and cooked.

Recooking cooked meat would not lead  to overcooking. The sort of overcooking you’re thinking of is actually overheating. It doesn’t relate to how long or how many times the meat is cooked.